# Mongoose, Sort Results by Reference Attributes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I will attempt to address the problem as clearly as possible.

Let's say I have two collections, **Col_A** and **Col_B**.

**Col_A** has an attribute, *attribute C*, that references our other collection, **Col_B**, via ObjectID.

[image for visual reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEO1V.png)

I want to query for documents from Col_A and sort by *attribute E* in **Col_B**.

A practical example, if the above is too broad, would be Users and Listings on a site like eBay. For this example, let's say **Col_A** is "**Listings**", **Col_B** is "**Users**", *attribute C* is "*seller*", and *attribute E* is "*rating*".

Query: *grab all listings matching some criteria, sorted by sellers with the highest rating*

That would mean "grab all documents from **Listings** matching some given criteria, and sort the results by the *rating* attribute for each **Users** document the listings reference.

How would one go about doing this? I understand how to apply basic sorting logic via mongoose, such as:

```
Listings.find({"attribute A" : "something"}).sort({"some_field": "uhh"}).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
```

, but can I nest in the attributes for referenced documents and sort by those? Do I need to somehow apply queries within the sort parameters or something? Is Mongoose capable of something like this? I looked at Mongoose's populate functionality, but I can't get anything working, and apparently there's a bug that discourages folks from actually using populated documents for sorting.

[Github Issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2202)

I apologize if this question has been answered already. I've been digging through the documentation, SO, and various other sites, but I can't get anything going. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use populate method to populate seller and the query would return an array like this:

```
[
    {
        title: 'Listing #1',
        seller: {
            name: 'John',
            rating: 100
        }
    }
    {
        title: 'Listing #2',
        seller: {
            name: 'John',
            rating: 20
        }
    }
]
```

then you can sort the data like this:

```
Listings.find({"attribute A" : "something"}).populate('seller').exec(function(err, docs) {
    docs.sort(function compare(a, b){
        let c = 0;    
        if (a.seller.rating > b.seller.rating) {
             c = 1;
        } else if (b.seller.rating > a.seller.rating) {
             c = -1;
        }    
        return c;
    });
    // return or response with docs
});
```

It might not be what you are looking but I tried :)
Mongo or Mongoose will not do this kind of `sort` since `populate` method makes 2 queries and Mongo doesn't know there's any relation between them.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick.

Sucks that there isn't a more elegant, mongoose-based solution. Oh well, it's not TOO bad. ;D Thanks!

Comment: Does this still work? Seems a and b appear in the function as you would expect, but im just getting an empty return response from what would be the Listings.find().exec() here

Comment: @LucasRahn i haven't used Mongo in years so i can't help. In the other hand i see no reason it wouldn't. The sorting is pure javascript no magic. You're probably just not returning the data properly.